Server loading and refreshing
i have some space at the faculty's student server and personal webpage there... But when i try to change index.html using ssh from the terminal and refresh in the browser everything is the same... Why?

It is unclear how this might be an Ubuntu-related question. Please edit your question to clarify.

It seems it is a server related question only, i has nothing to do with the ubuntu...

Would you tell me why it is happening or at least gimme some resource to read about it... ?
